# format number in XSLT with always 2 decimal place

Tags: xslt

Can anyone help me with XSLT code to convert as below

Input:
123456789
12345
123

Output:
1234567.89
123.45
1.23

I used below code

`<xsl:value-of select="format-number(Amount, '##.##')"/>`

Comment: Your starting point (the contents of `$nodes_in`) is not clear. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

To convert an amount like 123 to 1.23 (and 50 to 0.50), you need to do:

```
format-number($amount div 100, '0.00')
```

Comment: thanks for your input but i am getting below output                                          
  - Amount:'1234567'
  This input leads to the output:
12345.67 0.00

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you further unless you provide a way to reproduce the problem. Please edit your question and add a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, that's not enough. Show the **exact** input as it appears in XML. If you have multiple amounts, then also state which XSLT processor you are using.